# "tf.exe checkout" locks files although parameter /lock:none is used in post build

Tags: tfs, locking, post-build-event, vcs-checkout

In a customer project, I need to copy a built dll to another place where it will be checked in and shared amongst different solutions.

I am using a post build step to checkout the target file specifying the /lock:none parameter so that others will be able to create local release builds as well and then copy my new dll file over the old one.

However, when I use tf.exe checkout /lock:none  on a console prompt, everything works as expected. When used within a post build script, the file gets locked and nobody can check it out anymore.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First question is why do a "checkout" instead of just a "get"?  If you're not going to be changing the original file, there's no reason to do a checkout.

To answer the question specifically, though, the reason this is happening is that by default, executable files are set to not allow merging.  That means that-- no matter what-- a checkout on a DLL is going to be an exclusive checkout.

To change this behavior, in Visual Studio 2010:

1. Go to the `Team` menu
2. Select `Team Project Collection Settings`, then
3. select `Source Control File Types`
4. Find `Executable Files` in the file list, and Edit it to enable File Merging

Click on OK to commit your changes, and you should be good to go.

Comment: just for reminder, image files are also checked-out exclusively.